# Managing auto rotation in Storyboards

Tags: ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2, autorotate

I'm working on an app that has several storyboard scenes.
I'd like to support any rotation of the device.

When I start, the first scene  auto-rotataion works fine.  The problem seems to be when I add more scenes and connect them via segues.  Say, you click a menu button and segue to another scene... that next scene pops up in portrait mode and doesn't auto rotate...

Should I use a navigation controller to bring up the view and rotate it... Or am I not using the correct segue?

Answer (score 1):

All you scenes may or may not need to have their own subclass (depending on inheritance).  Assign the subclass to the respective scene.

You then need to set the supported rotation values in the subclass. eg.:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```